# Merge [fmx] with [firemonkey]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, retag-request, synonym-request

FMX is the Embarcadero acronym for [FireMonkey](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE5/en/FireMonkey_Application_Platform) application platform. 
Currently a number of questions have either of these tags, but their meaning is identical.

Can we mark [fmx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/fmx) as a synonym of [firemonkey](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/firemonkey) so the confusion goes away, right now if I want to see all FireMonkey questions I need to look for two tags.

Comment: We can do suggesting of synonyms by ourselves. You can [suggest it here](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/fmx/synonyms).

Comment: @TLama, did that.

Comment: Great. You've got my vote there (yet 2 more votes are missing for approval)!